# XML parsing with special characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, uitextfield, xml-parsing

In my iPhone app I have to display `UITextField` in-between in a large paragraph. Here I am getting this paragraph string is from a XML. Here how to insert `UITextField` in this paragraph in a particular position?

Here this XML in also contain some special characters to find the place where to insert the `UITextField`? So also how to parse the XML which as special characters in between and insert `UITextField`?

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: here the special characters in-between text are = $ & < >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you encode the XML before saving it or at least the data you are appending and decode it back on parsing.

[URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)

On receiving the XML use:

[CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html)

```
  NSString* sItemNameDecorated = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)@"UserName%26LastName", CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

This will output: **UserName&LastName**

---

***Example***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Persons Name="UserName&LastName />
```

after Encoding it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Persons Name="UserName%26LastName />
```

Comment: So this will only replace the special characters with NULL right ? . but here my question is inserting textfields in-between them.

Comment: Oh i never used it before can you please expain little details about this replacing functionality becoz when i am using CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding again am getting original string ie string with special characters. Thanks